# Can i replace a De-9 port with something else?

Tags: soldering, music, de9

I was given an old piece of DJ equipment from the late 90s and unfortunately, the only way to connect it to a pc, which is what its meant for, is through a De-9 port/cable. And my pc doesn't support that. I could, in theory, buy an adapter but I'd prefer not to so I was wondering if I can either make an adapter or somehow solder a different port type in place of the de-9. If it's not possible I'll just scrap it for parts for future projects but I want to at least see if it can be used. Even if I can replace it though it probably won't be useful since the software is for win 98 and Windows 10 doesn't support that as far as my knowledge goes

Comment: Buy a USB to RS232 dongle.

Comment: The 9 pin D-subminature connector commonly used for serial ports is Officially a DE-9 (E-size shell), although all D-subminature connectors are often incorrectly called "DB".  The only Real "DB" connector is the DB-25.  A standard-density "A" shell holds 15 contacts, "B" is 25, "C" is 37, and "D" is 50 (or so), and "E" is 9 contacts.

Comment: You could replace it with a different shaped connector but it won't help you because your computer still won't have the electronics to create the right signals. It doesn't matter what shape the connector is if the actual electricity is wrong. You can get a USB adapter for not a lot of money.

Comment: Would it even be worth doing though? I dont think that the thing itself is compatible with win 10

Comment: @PeterBennett ... i just learned something new today .... thank you

Comment: @scooter505, upvote  .... your question was indirectly useful

Comment: @jsotola thanks man XD

Comment: although it was marked as off topic and put on hold sadly